# Using Buffer in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, arraybuffer

I'm working on an Electron app that read and modify files and show the result in the browser.

The modify function seems like:

```
const offset = 16;
let file = readFileSync('<some-file>');

if (condition) {
    return file.subarray(offset);
}

return file;
```

In the frontend, I'm doing this:

```
new Blob(
    [file.buffer],
    { type }
)
```

The `file.buffer` is causing the problem after `file.subarry()` as it's still using the original reference.

**Original**:

```
console.log(file.length, file.buffer.byteLength); // 4075, 4091 (included the offset that should have trimmed)
```

**Approach 1**:

```
file.slice(offset);
console.log(file.length, file.buffer.byteLength); // 4075, 4075 (everything works fine)
```

**Approach 2**:

```
Buffer.from(file, offset, file.length - offset); // or
Buffer.copyBytesFrom(file, offset, file.length - offset);
console.log(file.length, file.buffer.byteLength); // 4075, 8192 (???)
```

**Approach 3**:

```
let buffer = Buffer.alloc(file.length - offset);
file.copy(buffer, 0, offset, file.length - offset); // TypeError: file.copy is not a function at __webpack_modules__../src.....
```

Question:

1. I know I could simply use `Buffer.slice` to solve it, but `Buffer.slice` is now deprecated. Is there a way to do exactly the same as `Buffer.slice`?
2. In **Approach 2**, why is the `file.buffer` using more bytelength?
3. Is it not recommended to use `Buffer` here? I didn't expect the `TypeError` occurs in **Approach 3**.
4. Following question 3, I've tried to rewrite the function with `Uint8Array`, and do the modification in the browser. The function works but when I replace the script for Electron, something related to buffer went wrong. Is there a better way to get rid of the buffer problems?

PS. This application is written in Typescript. I tried to install the NPM module `buffer` to polyfill(?) and hope it will solve the `TypeError` issue in **Approach 3**. But before I compile the code, Typescript is complaining everywhere.